# Odd intellisense behaviour in VS2012 using C++. Ignores #include?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have a header defined as follows

### header

```
#pragma once

#include <map>      
#include <string>
#include "gl\glew.h"
#include "glm\glm\glm.hpp"


class TextureAtlas
{
public:
    TextureAtlas(std::string fileName);
    ~TextureAtlas(void);

    // Returns the index of a sprite from its name
    //int getIndex(std::string name);

    // Returns the source rectangle for a sprite
    glm::vec4 getSourceRectangle(std::string name);

    // Returns the OpenGL texture reference
    GLuint getTexture();

    float getTextureHeight();
    float getTextureWidth();

private:
    float m_height;

    // Holds the sprite name and its index in the texture atlas
    //std::map<std::string, int> m_indices;

    // Holds the source rectangle for each sprite in the texture atlas
    std::map<std::string, glm::vec4> m_sourceRectangles;

    // The texture containing all of the sprite images
    GLuint m_texture;

    float m_width;
};
```

I'm getting errors with the following constructor for the associated source

### source

```
#include "TextureAtlas.h"
#include "Content\Protobuf\TextureAtlasSettings.pb.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>                                      // ifstream

#define LOCAL_FILE_DIR "Content\\"

TextureAtlas::TextureAtlas(std::string fileName)
{
    TextureAtlasSettings::TextureAtlasEntries settings;

    std::string filePath(LOCAL_FILE_DIR);
    filePath.append(fileName);

    ifstream file(filePath, ios::in | ios::binary);     // ERROR!

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        if (!settings.ParseFromIstream(&file)) 
        {
            printf("Failed to parse TextureAtlasEntry");
        }
    }

    int numEntries = settings.entries().size();

    for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++)
    {
        m_sourceRectangles[settings.entries(i).name()] = glm::vec4(
            settings.entries(i).x(),
            settings.entries(i).y(),
            settings.entries(i).height(),
            settings.entries(i).width()
            );
    }
}

TextureAtlas::~TextureAtlas(void)
{
}
```

The problem is

*IntelliSense: identifier "ifstream" is undefined*

If I put std:: infront of it (std::ifstream) then that removes the error above but causes the following error

*error C2653: 'ios' : is not a class or namespace name*

What is going on?  It doesn't make any sense as I think I have included everything I need?!

Comment: ifstream resides in std namespace, so you should declare it either by prefixing with `std::` or `using namespace std;` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code as you posted it you *have to* prefix the types with the namespace name, i.e. `std::ifstream` and `std::ios`.

Comment: I see.  Odd that I do not have to do that in some other classes, even when they have no using keyword?

Comment: No. You always have to do that unless there is a `using namespace std;` directive or `using std::ifstream;` (for example) declaration somewhere in the current translation unit (TU). In he first case you might use `ifstream`, `ios` and any other element from the standard library included in current TU without namespace prefix. In the latter case, you can use `ifstream` but not `std::ios`, or `std::cout`. This isn't a good practice IMHO and I would heartily recommend to avoid it.